# Painting on the MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing

I try to paint on my MainWindow. I use this sample code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("OnRender");

            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5), new Rect(20, 20, 250, 250));

            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
</Window>
```

In the output window I see the message "OnRender", but nothing is drawn.
[image: MainWindow and Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set `Background="Transparent"`in the Window's XAML. And always call `base.OnRender` before your own drawings, since you want to draw *over* the base class drawings (if any).

Comment: @Clemens thanks, do you want to post a response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `Background="Transparent"`in the Window's XAML.

And always call `base.OnRender` before your own drawings, since you want to draw *over* the base class drawings (if any).